# Binary Search seems to return random result

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, search

Before I start, I'm not asking about binary search, or how to solve this problem. 
My question is: 
 **Why am I getting weird results. What's going on under the hood to cause these results?** 
 Here goes: 
I'm trying to write an algorithm to search an ordered list of words. The only catch is, the lexigraphically ordered list starts somewhere in the middle of the alphabet, and I need to find the rotation point (the index of the "smallest" word). To break the problem down, I decided I'll first search for the biggest word, which will always be right before the smallest, then I'll worry about the index.
I did this. 
But then I started noticing weird results and got a little sidetracked. 
I'm using an [online interpreter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) and somehow I'm getting seemingly random results. I'm getting ***zi, yi, xi, wi,vo*** and sometimes ***d*** 
Here's what my list looks like: 
`words = list({'vo', 'wi', 'xi', 'yi', 'zi', 'ai', 'bi', 'ci', 'd'})`

and here's what my code looks like

```
low = 0
high = len(words)
mid = (high-low) // 2 + low
biggest_word = words[0]
while high-low > 1:
    if words[mid] > biggest_word:
        biggest_word = words[mid]
        high = mid
    else:
        low = mid
    mid = (high-low) // 2 + low
print (biggest_word)
```

Update: I've found that this issue only occurs in Python3. Python2 yields consistent results.

Comment: Shouldn't your list be sorted?

Comment: Regardless of Python version, the `//` operator has higher precedence than the `-` operator, so the expression `high-low // 2` does not mean what you appear to want it to mean.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The list as written does have an order. If you mean what FoolsWisdom said, then yeah, I'm new to Python

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `list({'vo', 'wi', 'xi', 'yi', 'zi', 'ai', 'bi', 'ci', 'd'})` first creates a set, then makes a list out of that set. A set is an unordered data structure, so the order in the list is random. It seems that in python 2 a set keeps insertion order nevertheless, but python 3 it does not.